# Why does ListBox.DisplayMember accept a string value?

Tags: c#, properties

I am currently very new to C#, with most of my knowledge coming from Java & Python. With that said, I currently have the following code:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Person_ID { get; set; }
    public String First_Name { get; set; }
    public String Last_Name { get; set; }
    public String EmailAddress { get; set; }


    public String FullInfo
    {
        get
        {
            // Matthew Arnold (mtthwrnld@gmail.com)
            return $"{First_Name}, {Last_Name}, ({EmailAddress})";
        }
    }

}
```

with the "FullInfo" property utilized here:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //'Results' is a ListBox
    //'people' is a List of type Person

    DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
    people = db.getPeople(lastNameText.Text);

    Results.DataSource = people;
    Results.DisplayMember = "FullInfo";
}
```

My question regards this line explicitly: `Results.DisplayMember = "FullInfo";`

How does this assignment *actually* work? We are setting the `DisplayMember` to the `FullInfo` property, yet we are wrapping it in a `String`. Why do we not simply do `Results.DisplayMember = Person.FullInfo`?

How does the compiler know this is not any old `String`? What are the benefits of accessing the property in this manner?

Comment: Because when you set the `DisplayMember`, it looks at the `DataSource` for that object property... If you do `Results.DisplayMember = Person.FullInfo`, it does not represent an instance of the person class, rather it's telling it to look for a property called `Person.FullInfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with reflection here. Take a look at this function:

```
public static void GetDisplayName(object anyType, string displayName)
{
    var type = anyType.GetType();

    var displayProperty = type.GetProperty(displayName);
    if (displayProperty != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"DisplayName is {displayProperty.GetValue(anyType)}");
        return;
    }

    var displayFiled = type.GetField(displayName);
    if (displayFiled != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"DisplayName is {displayFiled.GetValue(anyType)}");
        return;
    }

    // can't find displayName
    Console.WriteLine($"DisplayName is {type.Name}");
}
```

If you call it like

```
var person = new Person
{
    Person_ID = 42,
    First_Name = "First",
    Last_Name = "Last",
    EmailAddress = "name@domain.com"
};

GetDisplayName(person, "FullInfo");
```

It will print

> DisplayName is First, Last, (name@domain.com)

Just like in your example in the question we only pass `"FullInfo"` into it as string. But inner code of `ListBox` smart enough to use this string as a map to actual value

Comment: Thanks. Might take my head some time to fully wrap around Reflection, but this clears my question up nicely.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we not simply do Results.DisplayMember = Person.FullInfo?

This would set the value of `DisplayMember` to the string that FullInfo returns. The value of `DisplayMember` is meant to be the name of the property holding the value to be displayed.

You could set it in the following way, which is what I recommend:

```
Results.DataSource = people;
Results.DisplayMember = nameof(person.FullInfo);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the `nameof` operator is only available since C# 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

ListBox uses [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) internally while displaying data from it's datasource. In C#, Reflection is powerful mechanism where you can access i.e object fields by having only *name* of the field as string.

You can try reflection with following snippet:

```
var person = new Person{First_Name = "FirstName", Last_Name="LastName", Person_ID=12, EmailAddress="email@email.com"};
var fullInfo = person.GetType().GetProperty("FullInfo").GetValue(person, null);
```